# ASN.1 DER encoding for CHOICE in Golang

Tags: go, encoding, asn.1

I am trying to create an DER encoded ASN.1 blob in Golang.

I have the inner TLV explicitly defined as a `struct` which maps to a `SEQUENCE` in ASN.1. This SEQUENCE is to be embedded in a CHOICE type. Refer ASN.1 schema [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-thomas-crypto-conditions-02).

I thought the easiest way to do this would be to use then `encoding/asn1.RawValue` type.

Referring to the section on encoding in [this amazing book](http://www.oss.com/asn1/resources/books-whitepapers-pubs/dubuisson-asn1-book.PDF) and using this [online ASN.1 tool](http://asn1-playground.oss.com/), I understand that my binary (depicted in HEX below) should start with `A0258020...`.

However, my result is `30258020...`.

I have localized the problem to encoding the `CHOICE` type in Golang.
In the expected case, it is a `Context-Specific, Constructed, Tag:0` tag (as per the reference book above), but I get a `Universal, Primitive, Tag:1` type, where `Tag:1` maps to a sequence in ASN.1.

I try to set the outer `CHOICE` header as:

```
    serializedCondition, err := asn1.Marshal(asn1.RawValue{
        Class:      2, // or asn1.ClassContextSpecific
        IsCompound: true, // as CHOICE it is a Constructed type and not Primitive type
        Tag:        0, // Zero in my case
        FullBytes: serialized, // The serialized inner sequence of bytes
    })
```

Can someone explain how to we use the inbuilt ASN.1 library in Golang with the low-level `RawValue` or `RawContent` type to serialize objects tagged as `CHOICE`, `SET OF`, `SEQUENCE OF` in ASN.1.

Comment: I'm very happy that I haven't use crap like ASN.1 for nearly 15 years, and I also prefer a bit shorter and more readable Layman's guide. But your issue probably has something to do with is wrong tag. 30 is sequence, and a0 is because your tag was overriden be [0] IMPLICIT. Sorry I don't want to study how to use asn.1 in go, because I love go and I hate ASN.1. Both with passion

Comment: And [0] means val.Class = Application

Comment: @lofcek: I didn't quite get `And [0] means val.Class = Application `. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Hups .. I was wrong .. From Layman - "If the class name is absent, then the tag is context- specific.", therefore class should be ClassContextSpecific.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been researching the choice of ASN. 1 in Golang recently. This looks okay.
e := EventContent{
Class:      2,
Tag:        0,
IsCompound: true,
Bytes:      serialized,
}

serialized：300e800100a309800101820102830102
e:a010300e800100a309800101820102830102

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).